# Calling CoffeeScript file for html form validation using external reference

Tags: html, coffeescript

I am a beginner with CoffeeScript doing my first html validation.
I can't get my html form validated.
The code goes like this:

```
<script type="text/coffeescript">
usernameValidate = ->
  x = document.getElementById("username").value
  ptrn = /^[A-z0-9]{5,8}$/
    if ptrn.test(x)
      document.getElementById("usrmsg").innerHTML = ""
      barwidth = barwidth + 10
      document.getElementById("progress").style.width = barwidth + "%"
      return true
    else
      y = "Only Alpha Numeric and Length between 5-8 chars"
      document.getElementById("usrmsg").innerHTML = "<img src='./icons/error.png'>" + y
      document.getElementById("progress").style.width = barwidth + "%"
      document.getElementById("username").focus()
      return false
barwidth = 0
 </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/coffee-script.js"></script>
```

and the html:

```
<input type="text" name="uname" placeholder="User Name" id="username" onblur="usernameValidate()">
<span id="usrmsg"></span>
<div class="progress progress-striped active" id="progressbar">
<div class="bar" id="progress"></div>
</div>
```

I have used twitter bootstrap for progress bar.
I want
 - The progress bar to increase in width for valid username
 - Error msg should displayed if input is not a valid pattern

Please suggest where I went wrong.
I thank you in advance

Comment: Did you try debugging it using either Firebug or the debugger in Chrome? If not, try stepping through the code and see what happens.

Comment: The variable ``barwidth`` seems to be out of place. As I read the code, it isn't initialized before it is used.

Comment: Is that your real indentation? And making the clients compile your CoffeeScript is a bad idea, you should be doing that server-side so that you only have to do it once.

Comment: @mu is too short thank you for your suggestion

Comment: I deeply appreciate any more ways and suggestions.
thank you :)

Comment: One way I found is, adding the jQuery through
    <script src="../jquery.js"> </script>
and binding the event through plugin
    $("#pswrd").bind "blur", ->
     pwdValidate()'
just before the function declaration,I could make the validation possible

Comment: @mzedeler that came in handy thankyou

Comment: Ok. Did it solve the problem?

Comment: @mzedeler declaring the variable before the function or leaving a line after writing the function, the variable seems to work.
If you are asking about my solution, yes it did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First fix your indentation so that you have valid CoffeeScript:

```
usernameValidate = ->
  x = document.getElementById("username").value
  ptrn = /^[A-z0-9]{5,8}$/
  if ptrn.test(x)
    document.getElementById("usrmsg").innerHTML = ""
    barwidth = barwidth + 10
    document.getElementById("progress").style.width = barwidth + "%"
    return true
  else
    y = "Only Alpha Numeric and Length between 5-8 chars"
    document.getElementById("usrmsg").innerHTML = "<img src='./icons/error.png'>" + y
    document.getElementById("progress").style.width = barwidth + "%"
    document.getElementById("username").focus()
    return false
barwidth = 0
```

I'd move `barwidth` to the top but it shouldn't matter as the variable will be hoisted to the top anyway and it will be initialized before `usernameValidate` runs.

I see two other possible problems:

1. Your CoffeeScript might be getting compiled to JavaScript for the browser *after* your `<input>` has been seen.
2. `<script type="text/coffeescript">` probably wraps everything in a self execute function wrapper just like the usual `coffee` command does.

The second one can be fixed by forcing your function into the global namespace:

```
@usernameValidate = -> ...
# or
window.usernameValidate = -> ...
```

`@` (AKA `this`) in this context should be `window` so you should be able to use `@usernameValidate`.

Solving the first one is a bit more work. Your best bet here would be to stop pretending that it is 1995 and abandon the `onblur` attribute in favor of [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) or a library that does that for you. If you go this route then **2** goes away as you can bind your event handler without having to pollute the global namespace.